# Creating JPA Specification with lookup in Embeddable entities

Tags: jpa

I have an entity Task which is assigned to Users.

```
@Entity
public class Task {

   @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(
            name = "USERS",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "TASK_ID")
    )
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
}
```

User is an Embeddable looking like this

```
@Embeddable
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User{

    private UUID userId;

}
```

I need to write a specification that takes a Set of user Ids and returns all tasks, where at least one of the given users is assigned to. My current approach is like this:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class IsTaskAssignedToUser implements Specification<Task> {

    private final Set<UUID> userIds;


    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(final Root<Task> task, final CriteriaQuery<?> query, final CriteriaBuilder builder) {
        return builder.or(
                this.userIds.stream()
                        .map(user-> builder.in(task.get("users").get("userId")))
                        .toArray(Predicate[]::new));
    }


}
```

However this does not return any results. How can this be achieved, I cannot add a back reference to task from user for reasons beyond my control.